Improving Data Sets by Adding New Nodes
I have an idea for adding new nodes into a directed graph to achieve a numerically stable graph Fourier transform for signal analysis in the graph domain. To assess its efficiency, I am looking for  real-world datasets structured as directed graphs for testing.

Here are two data sources lists that you can browse to find such graphs:

scikit-network's NetSet, in particular the wikivitals dataset;
Pytorch geometric datasets
I don't think they all qualify as "real-world" but some of them surely do.

